# CCSprite doesn't go invisible -iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

in .h file

```
CCSprite *backwheels;

in .m file

    backwheels = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"wheels_back.png"];
    backwheels.position = ccp(400,120);
    [self addChild:backwheels];

-(void) showGameOver {
      backwheels.visible = false;
}
```

but when Game is Over backWheels still appears on scene..? !
any help ?!
NOTE:i have synthesized backWheels too,but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: does showGameOver even get called?

Comment: Yes,ofcourse..
i have another CCSprite object which is also reside in showGameOver method and it doesn't visible when i wrote cannon.visible = false;

Comment: the only possible reason which comes to my mind without seeing the rest of your code is that your backwheels pointer doesn't point to the actual sprite shown on the screen

Comment: but i have also synthesized it but still doesn't work.

Comment: starting from Xcode 4.5 you don't need to synthesize properties anymore. and synthesizing it or not has no relation to the question. try checking in showGameOver method - can you change anything else of your backwheels except visibility. i'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to change its rotation or scale, or color. check it

Comment: i m using Xcode 4.2.1 ;)
anyways,YES you are right i havee chang it's position but it didn't change..

Comment: @V.D just wanna make sure that i'm wrong about "retain" did you tried that ???

Comment: @Hamdullahshah please explain what kind of relation do you see between extra-retaining the sprite and the subject?

Comment: @V.D it means that somewhere previously in your code you made the pointer backwheels point to a different direction

Comment: @Hamdullah shah retain and release have another concept.i can't use retain here.

Comment: @V.D just for a test :-)

Comment: @AndreyChernukha as u have the autorelease reference and the node in which u added the sprite have the retain reference because node added that in array. Then what if u add that sprite to some other node not "self" and the node is released your another reference is also gone?? :-)

Comment: @AndreyChernukha When you search backWheels in my Xcode you will find only 4 matches.
It doesn't concern with Z Property right ?!

Comment: @V.D 100 percent it's not about z property

Comment: @Hamdullahshah i have also tried with retain but it doesn't work(Ofcourse it should not work !! ) ... 
Happy ?!  ;)

Comment: ugh, upgrade Xcode, no point in not using the latest build. One thing to make sure is that you don't actually create 2 or more backwheel sprites.

Comment: did you fix this bug?

Comment: Nope,i am not able to make it :(

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a quick fix. This is not the best approach, the best one is to find out what exactly causes such a behavior, but i can't do that without seeing the rest of your code. Anyway this is how you can access backwheels sprite in `showGameOver` method. When you create the sprite make it this way:

```
 backwheels = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"wheels_back.png"];
 backwheels.position = ccp(400,120);
 backwheels.tag = 100; // whatever integer value you wish
[self addChild:backwheels];
```

Then you retrieve it in `showGameOver` :

```
backwheels = [self getChildByTag:100];
backwheels.visible = false;
```

I believe it's gonna work.

Comment: You won't believe but it doesn't work for me either.
and it shows me warning in showGameOver method "incompetible pointer type assigning to CCSprite* from CCNode *"

Comment: try CCNode *test = [self getChildByTag:100]; test.visible = false;

Comment: Still the same..
I don't know why it doesn't work..i swear i didn't Write any code for backwheels except the code which is mention above.. :(

Comment: check address of backwheels right after you created it :  backwheels = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"wheels_back.png"]; NSLog(@"%p", backwheels); and address of the object you retrieve by tag NSLog(@"%p", [self getChildByTag:100); and tell me if they're equal or not

Comment: Problem is Solved..!! @Andrey Cheernukha  Thank you so much for your valuable time.. :)

Comment: so what was causing the issue? i'm just curious

Comment: Leave, You will slap me. :(
silly mistake !! 
This operation should be in LevelCompletion method and i wrote in showGameOver method...
i don't know what was running in my mind !!
anyways,thank you so much for your valuable time..

Answer (score 0):

You could always just change the opacity of the sprite i.e.

```
-(void) showGameOver {
      backwheels.opacity = 0.0f;
}
```

And then when you want it to reappear change it to

```
backwheels.opacity = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Remove Child :

```
[self removeChild:backwheels cleanup:YES];
```

Comment: Why downvote ????    If you want to remove all the Child from the View you can also use            [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];

Comment: i didn't downvote.but YES i will if i would have enough reputation..anyways,when im using visible or setVisible property it means that i want to use that CCsprite object later..Removing child is not the Solution.